# Flask Error json not serialized

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, flask

I have created an application that uses commandline and call the program.

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, make_response, request 

import os
import subprocess
import json
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/api/v1.0/qanda/', methods=['GET'])

def people_api():
    text = request.args.get('text')
    Answer = subprocess.Popen(['programcall', repr(text)],stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]

    if text is None:
           make_response(jsonify({'error': 'Missing text parameter'}), 400)
    return jsonify(Answer)
app.run('0.0.0.0')
```

What I am trying to get is the PRETTY JSON OUTPUT on the application when I hit the browser URL. I tried to display the output but it was not pretty Json and most of the time jsonify was giving error: JSON is not serialized.

Kindly show me the way through which I can display the proper result using my application
One error which I can across is this:

```
    Answer = Answer + subprocess.Popen(['programcall', repr(text)],stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "bytes") to list
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to [wait](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.wait) for your `subprocess` to finish before you can read the output.  That is why sometimes you get the error and sometimes not because sometimes the process finishes and you have the output.